# Not show Menu on certain pages in MVC 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am developing an MVC 3 webiste.  I have a jquery menu on the site.  Not all pages use the menu.  So the logon page or logout if not authorized page do not have the menu.  I have done this by have a RenderSection like below in my _Layout page.

```
 @RenderSection("Menu", required: false)
```

Then in the pages that should have the menu I have included the section as below:

```
@section Menu{
    <ul id="menu" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin-right: 10px; z-index: 9999;">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("History", "ViewHistory", "History", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
        <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Reports</a>
            <ul style="z-index: 9999;">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("File Report", "ViewFileReport", "Reports", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
                <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">New Files</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Old Files</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Admin</a>
            <ul style="z-index: 9999;">
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

As i am now adding to the menu and changing things I and adding more pages I am realising having this RenderSection on all the pages I need it but not on my LogOn page or First Landing pages is combersome as I have to edit it in 8/9 places currently and that will only grow.  What would be a better way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you want to put your menu markup in your `_Layout.cshtml`, but only render it if required.

You can put a `bool` value in your `ViewBag` to turn on the menu in the pages that require it.

In your controller actions, put:

```
ViewBag.ShowMenu = true;
```

Then in `_Layout.cshtml` you can put a condition like this:

```
@if ( ViewBag.ShowMenu == true )
{
  <ul id="menu" ... your menu markup here
  </ul>
}
```

Comment: Many Thanks for you prompt response Nicolas - I will try this and mark the answer as acepted if it works :).

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to a file in `App_Code` folder, like this:

`App_Code\Helpers.cshtml`:

```
@helper Menu()
{
    <ul id="menu" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; margin-right: 10px; z-index: 9999;">
        <li>@Html.GetPageHelper().ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
        <li>@Html.GetPageHelper().ActionLink("History", "ViewHistory", "History", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
        <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Reports</a>
            <ul style="z-index: 9999;">
                <li>@Html.GetPageHelper().ActionLink("File Report", "ViewFileReport", "Reports", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
                <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">New Files</a></li>
                <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Old Files</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a class="menu-text" href="#">Admin</a>
            <ul style="z-index: 9999;">
                <li>@Html.GetPageHelper().ActionLink("Change Password", "ChangePassword", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>@Html.GetPageHelper().ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Home", null, new { @class = "menu-text" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

And add another class to your project for the method `GetPageHelper()` which is required to get `HtmlHelper<T>` instance from codes in `App_Code`:

```
public static class PageHelper
{
    public static HtmlHelper<object> GetPageHelper(this System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return ((WebViewPage)WebPageContext.Current.Page).Html;
    }

    public static UrlHelper GetUrlHelper(this System.Web.WebPages.Html.HtmlHelper html)
    {
        return ((WebViewPage) WebPageContext.Current.Page).Url;
    }
}
```

Now you can use your menu like this in your Views or Layouts:

```
@Helpers.Menu()
```